# What happens with jungle respawns when you don't fully clear creeps?

Tags: league-of-legends

Supposedly you can harass the enemy jungle a little by killing the valuable creeps in a jungle pack and leaving one of the cheap minions around to delay a full respawn.  How does this work exactly?  If I see a solo minion up at one of our buffs, should I kill it or let it be?  Is there a difference between leaving two minions up and coming back later and killing another to delay a buff/respawn?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A given camp will not respawn unless ALL of it's creeps in that camp is first dead. Only then will the respawn timer start up.

If it's a camp on your side of the jungle that has only one creep left, make sure to kill that creep so that camp actually respawns.

A great way to counter jungle is to steal all of the creeps except for one of the small creeps per camp. The enemy jungle will have to kill that creep and wait the full respawn time for the camp to come back.

#### [Jungle Timers](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Jungling#Jungle_Overview)

```
 Camp        |  Spawn  | Respawn
-------------+---------+---------
 Wolves      |   1:55  |   0:50
 Wraiths     |   1:55  |   0:50
 Golems      |   1:55  |   0:50
 Blue Golem  |   1:55  |   5:00
 Red Lizard  |   1:55  |   5:00
 Dragon      |   2:30  |   6:00
 Baron       |  15:00  |   7:00
```

Comment: I was curious about this.  I saw conflicting information about whether it was a "doesn't respawn anything until all creeps are dead and the respawn timer finishes" and "it just adds time to the camp's respawn timer".

Comment: @Brandon If the respawn time for the red lizard is 5 min, and there is one minion left. Then the respawn timer for 5 min will count when you kill this one. Now leaving a minion in the jungle may be a good idea, but if you kill them all you know when the buff is gonna spawn oposed to if the enemy jungler kills the last one he will know when it respawns...

Comment: Great answer. Just adding something: This is the reason that people when are doing Counter Jungle left one small minion in the opponent camp. Stealing the wolfs and leaving one small, or both smalls sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the question is not very specific so I split the question and put the answers for each question inside of it:

> Supposedly you can harass the enemy jungle a little by killing the valuable creeps in a jungle pack and leaving one of the cheap minions around to delay a full respawn. How does this work exactly?

The mechanic of camps are: they will respawn *only* after all minions from that camp are dead. the counter start by the time the last minion die.

> If I see a solo minion up at one of our buffs, should I kill it or let it be?

You should clear it. Unless the camp is blue or red and you believe that none of your team (including you) will get in the respawn time.

> Is there a difference between leaving two minions up and coming back later and killing another to delay a buff/respawn?

[NO](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Monster#Notes), "A monster camp will not respawn unless all of its creeps have been slain. For example, if the  Lizard Elder has been slain, but his two smaller lizard companions have not, the [Lizard Elder](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lizard_Elder) will not respawn until they have been slain. Jungle invaders may deliberately do this to deprive their opponent of jungle gp/exp."

Extras:

Today (03-09-2012) respawn timers:

- [Wraith](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Wraith) - 1:00/1:15 (Depend if you are in  Summoner's Rift or Twisted Treeline)
- [Wolf](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Wolf) - 1:00
- [Golem](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Golem) - 1:00/1:15 (Depend if you are in  Summoner's Rift or Twisted Treeline)
- [Ghast](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ghast) - 3:00
- [Rabid Wolf](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rabid_Wolf) - 3:00
- [Grez](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Grez) - 4:00
- [Ancient Golem](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ancient_Golem) - 5:00
- [Lizard Elder](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lizard_Elder) - 5:00
- [Ebonmaw](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ebonmaw) - 5:00
- [Dragon](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon) - 6:00
- [Baron Nashor](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Baron_Nashor) - 7:00

Comment: FYI, Wraiths respawn every 50 seconds on Summoners Rift, not every minute.

Comment: Well i got the info from League of legends Wiki, so ... they are wrong or you are mistaken.

Comment: "It can be found amongst three Lesser Wraiths on Summoner's Rift, where it respawns every 50 seconds, and in a similar group on Twisted Treeline where it respawns in 75 seconds instead." directly from LoL Wiki