# What are the Jungle Respawn Times?

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legends, what are the jungle monster re-spawn times. Also at what time do they initially appear?

Comment: I did not see this information on the site and wound up looking for it so I wanted to add the information I found to the site.

Comment: Found Summoner's Rift data, but [since it's a complete tangent](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52613/what-happens-with-jungle-respawns-when-you-dont-fully-clear-creeps), then this was perfectly fine. Thanks for helping promote discoverability!

Comment: There are also mobile apps with which you can tap icons to see a counter for you. I haven't tested them and don't know about their up-to-dateness. They also may decimate your game experience. Example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.co.dcnim.loltimer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Summoner's Rift (5v5)**

- Buffs: 5 minutes respawn time, first spawn at 1:55
- Dragon: 6 minutes respawn time, first spawn at 2:30
- Baron: 7 minutes respawn time, first spawn at 15:00
- Wolves and Double Golems: 50 seconds respawn time, first spawn at 1:55
- Wraiths and Wight: 50 seconds respawn time, first spawn at 1:55

**Twisted Treeline (3v3)** Note: Twisted Treeline has been deprecated.

- Golems Wolves and Wraiths: 50 seconds between respawns, all camps first spawn at 1:40
- Vilemaw: 5 Minute respawn timer, first appears at 10 minutes

Comment: Also, I believe Baron adds HP the longer it is not attacked.

Comment: @Alok - actually, Baron gains more HP depending on how long the game was going, no matter of being attacked or not (9876 + 125/1min). Dragon has a part of HP depending on the highest level of a character in the game (3200 + (220 * highest champion level)).

Comment: Wolves & Double Golems now spawn in 50 seconds as well. You should also update the TT jungle details.